# How tovisualize local csv file with javascript using d3?

Tags: javascript, html, csv, d3.js, data-visualization

I'm trying to visualize my local csv file with javascript. As I was trying to make a bar graph and wanted to have x Axis  "disease name" and y Axis "Anzahl" which is occurence . But having an error which I can not find can anyone help?

I was trying to visualize my csv data with d3 library.
here is example from my local csv file.

```
>A00-A09,(Intestinal infectious diseases),154,
>A15-A19,(Tuberculosis),19440,
>A20-A28,(Certain zoonotic bacterial diseases),17237,
>A30-A49,(Other bacterial diseases),11233,
>A50-A64,(Infections with a predominantly sexual mode of transmission),49851
>A65-A69 (Other spirochaetal diseases),4582,
```

and here is what I have been trying.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
font: 10px sans-serif;
}
.axis path,
.axis line {

  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}

.bar {
  fill: orange;
}

.bar:hover {
  fill: orangered ;
}

.x.axis path {
  display: none;
}

.d3-tip {
  line-height: 1;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 12px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

/* Creates a small triangle extender for the tooltip */
.d3-tip:after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 1;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: "\25BC";
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Style northward tooltips differently */
.d3-tip.n:after {
  margin: -1px 0 0 0;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
}
</style>
<body>
<script src="http://dimplejs.org/dist/dimple.v2.0.0.min.js"></script>   
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://labratrevenge.com/d3-tip/javascripts/d3.tip.v0.6.3.js"></script>
<script type = "text/javascript">

var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .tickFormat(formatPercent);

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Anzahl:</strong> <span style='color:red'>" + d.Anzahl + "</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);


                chart.addSeries("nationality",dimple.plot.bar); // plotting,
                chart.draw();
            });
d3.csv("csv_data.csv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.letter; }));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.Anzahl; })]);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", ".71em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Anzahl");

  svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.letter); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.Anzahl); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.Anzahl); })
      .on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide)

});

function type(d) {
  d.Anzahl = +d.Anzahl;
  return d;
}

</script>
```

I expect the output which has x axis elements as A00-A09 and y axis as 154 which is occurence from A00-A09